# Convergence with indicator functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-measure

I'm a bit confused when I'm trying to solve some exercise using conceps like pointwise convergence, a.e. convergence and $L_\infty$ convergence with indicator functions. For example, we consider $f_n (x)=\mathcal{X}_{[n,n+1]}(x)$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in (0,\infty)$. It seems pretty obvius that $f_n\not\longrightarrow 0$, but here is my first dobut. If $n$ is large enough, in such a way that $x\notin [n,n+1]$, then $f_n (x)=0 \;\forall x\in (0,\infty)$, so $f_n=0$ pointwise. I know this can't be correct, but I need a second explanation. On the other hand, $f_n\longrightarrow 0$ a.e., but now $f_n=1$ if $x\in[n,n+1]$ and $\mu ([n,n+1])\neq 0$. Finally, why $||f_n||_\infty=1$?

Comment: $f(x)$ is defined on all the reals and $f_n(x) = 1$ for $x$ between $n$ and $n+1$. The infinity norm is 1 because $f(x)$ is either $0$ or $1$, so the largest value it can be is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointwise convergence means you look at some fixed $x\in(0,\infty)$ and you ask whether $f_n(x)\to 0$. You do this for each and every $x$ in your domain separately.

In this example it is certainly true that $f_n\to 0$ everywhere, because for any fixed $x\in(0,\infty)$ there's $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough such that $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n\geq n_0$. You say "If n is large enough, in such a way that $x\notin [n,n+1]$..." but this sentence is meaningless: which $x$ are you referring to? For any fixed $x$ we can find $n$ that is large enough, but we can't find $n$ that is large enough for all $x$.

(Since $f_n\to 0$ pointwise then in particular $f_n\to 0$ a.e. -- after all, it converges everywhere).

Regarding $L_\infty$, this is simply because the norm of each and every element of the sequence $f_n$ is $1$. Therefore you get a constant sequence which certainly converges to $1$.

Comment: So in this example there is pointwise convergence?

Comment: @Robert Yes. For every $x\in (0,\infty)$ you have $f_n(x)\to 0$. This means that $f_n\to 0$ pointwise on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Perfect! Thanls mate!